# "Два рубля" — какой вид связи?

Tags: синтаксис

"Два рубля" - это согласование?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, это управление.В им. пад. числительное управляет существительным.Два чего? - рубля. Но в других падежах будет согласование: двух рублей, двумя рублями, о двух рублях.